# Regex to extract only the a href who have a specifc word in <a>

Tags: c#, regex

I have this html :

```
<a href="https://m.com/link/NX1B4efPlb2Es3xh1ip" target="_blank" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; cursor: pointer; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;">Specific word</a>
```

And I'm looking for a regex who extract the href only of the link who have "Specific word" text :

Extract the href `https://m.com/link/NX1B4efPlb2Es3xh1ip` when the text `<a>` is `Specific word`.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Is `<a href="something" more="attributes">only text content</a>` really your only possible input, or do you want to pick that specific tag out of arbitrary HTML? Because the latter isn't possible.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to do it with Regex, I would suggest something like this:

```
/.*href=\"(.*?)\".*>Specific word.*/g
```

Explanation:

- `.*` matches every possible beginning
- `href` matches the word href
- `\"` matches the "
- `(.*?)` is a non-greedy match for the href content, which stores the result in the *capture group* (the capture group is what you are looking for)
- `\"` matches the closing "
- `.*>` matches the rest of the tag until it is closed
- `Specific word` matches the specific word
- `.*` matches all the rest.

Comment: I would suggest a XML parser.

Comment: Thank you markus for your help but the regex match all the sentence and not only the href in #, online tester : [the regex C# tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*href%3d%5c%22%28.*%3f%29%5c%22.*%3eSpecific+word.*&i=%3ca+href%3d%22https%3a%2f%2fm.com%2flink%2fNX1B4efPlb2Es3xh1ip%22+target%3d%22_blank%22+style%3d%22-ms-text-size-adjust%3a+100%25%3b+-webkit-text-size-adjust%3a+100%25%3b+cursor%3a+pointer%3b+word-wrap%3a+break-word%3b+word-break%3a+break-word%3b+color%3a+%23FFFFFF%3b+text-decoration%3a+none%3b%22%3eSpecific+word%3c%2fa%3e%0d%0a)

Comment: It matches the whole string but captures the link target (the parenthesized bit), just use that capture to extract the target.

Comment: @timothylhuillier As Pezo said, just use the capture group and you are good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use capturing groups like so:

```
Regex query = new Regex(".*href=\"(?<link>.*?)\".*>(?<name>.*?)</a>");
```

and then validate the result

```
Match match = query.Match(input);

if (match.Success && match.Groups["name"].Value == "Specific Word")
{
    // Do something with match.Groups["link"].Value
}
```

If you have potentially multiple results you could loop through like so:

```
MatchCollection mc = query.Matches(page);
foreach (Match m in mc){
    if(m.Groups["name"].Value == "Specific Word")
    {
        // Do something with m.Groups["link"].Value
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work if href is not the first attribute of the link. I would not trust the order of HTML attributes.
Also, it does not work if the link has mutliple attributes (which is the case in OP's question).

Comment: Changed regex query to fix this

Comment: Thank you, but I only can use regex, not additional code.